# Dual regression error (multiple files in a text file)

Tags: command-line, error-handling, regression

So I'm running into some trouble using dual_regression.  The problem here is that I'm using the following command and getting the following error:

```
>    macminngh:session_one_and_three sondosayyash$ dual_regression /Users/sondosayyash/Downloads/FIX_sNorm/40_subjects.gica/groupmelodic.ica/melodic_IC.nii.gz 1 -1 5000 dualreg_40subj_output.dr 'cat /Users/sondosayyash/Desktop/Users.txt'
/Users/sondosayyash/abin/fsl/bin/dual_regression: line 126: [: too many arguments
mkdir: dualreg_40subj_output.dr: File exists
mkdir: dualreg_40subj_output.dr/scripts+logs: File exists
creating common mask
/bin/sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `dualreg_40subj_output.dr/scripts+logs/drA'
/bin/sh: line 1: `file (dualreg_40subj_output.dr/scripts+logs/drA) does not exist -T 5 -N drB -l dualreg_40subj_output.dr/scripts+logs dualreg_40subj_output.dr/scripts+logs/drB'
doing the dual regressions
sorting maps and running randomise
/bin/sh: line 1: you: command not found
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong.

As for the text file listed as 'Users.txt' has many different file directories to filtered_func data.

I have a feeling there is a problem with the text file but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Is there an example file you can run as a test to see if you get any similar errors?

Comment: I figured this out, thanks :)